# Indexing columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActiveHistory]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [VARCHAR](250) NOT NULL,
    [ActiveID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [INT] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ActiveHistory] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
```

About 600,000 rows are inserted into the table per day that means 300,000 distinct actives for one date with about 500 distinct users. I would like to have about 5 year history in one table that means more then bln rows, in overall about 4,000 distinct userid and 1,000,000 distinct actives are placed in 5 year table. it is very important for me to work faster with this table,

Most of the queries in the past used joins with date and userid but in last days I have to include activeid quite often, but sometimes just two of them could be used (any pairs).

I never use ID in join.

Now I have nonclustered index with userid and date as index key columns and ID and ActiveID as included columns, Now my question is - how to best arrange the index for this table considering new challenges, just add all options as index may use huge place and sometimes application that uses the same server is suffering as CPU usage goes to 99%, I am not sure how new indexes will effect on that.

Comment: What indexes you need/want completely depends on the type of queries you perform against the table. If you, however, never use `ID` in your `WHERE` or `ON` is does seem like a poor `CLUSTERED INDEX` candidate.

Comment: Also, why do you have a column called `Date` that isn't a Date and time data type (it's a `varchar(250)`)? If it isn't a date and time, it isn't a Date; so the name doesn't make sense. I also can't think of any dates that are 250 characters long. At most that would be 27 characters (e.g. `'2019-01-03T11:12:17.0000000'`), but then that's a string, ***not*** a date.

Comment: Use appropriate data types for starters. What kinds of values can `ActiveID` contain? is it just 0 and 1? Once you hvae fixed all of your data types (including the date ones already mentioned, you might find that a clustered coumnstore speeds things up. However the question is really what queries are you running?

Comment: Table is created 3 years ago, now I have to recreate table with rational properties, Activeid should be int, it is id (identity) of another table, example of date is - '2019-01-03', I need to recreate table for analytical purpose, I am going to create new table, for date maybe it is better to have hashed string, I need just date, no need of time. I was going to change it as varchar(10) but your advice could be very important for me also in this issue.

Comment: About ID I also thought to remove it from index, but maybe it is good idea to have ID as alocator for nonclustered indexes, as I red there should be unic alocator anyway.
once more, thank you for your time, and happy new year

Comment: Why would you think a hashed string is a good data type for a date? use a date! Again choice of clustered, non clusteres (and clumstore) indexes depends primarily on the queries running aganst the table.

Comment: thank you Nick for advice on date format,
about queries - I have to use multiple joins mainly by Activeid and userid with date in 'where' criteria

Comment: Is it a single date or a date range (BETWEEN). If it's a date range, then I suggest a clustered index on on `[Date]` (after you fix the data type) and a nonclustered indexes on `ActiveId` and `userid`. If you always search on these in combination, then put both columns in the non clustered index.

Comment: You say _it is very important for me to work faster with this table,_ My advice is - pay someone to come in for a few days and help. Either that or you're going to have a waste a lot of time with trial and error trying to work it out. But in the first instance, _fix the data types_